# Live video transcoding with rails and ffmpeg (Streamed Upload)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I am working on a rails app where a user can upload a video of any format and that gets converted to mp4 using ffmpeg.  I am interested to reduce the time taken to convert a file to mp4. I know that ffmpeg can take a stream as the input and transcode it. So, while the file is getting uploaded if i can pass this stream to ffmpeg it can convert the file as it gets uploaded. Transloadt.com does this live encoding using nodejs and formidable. (https://transloadit.com/blog/2010/12/realtime-encoding-over-150x-faster). Is there any way we can do it using rails ?

I am using 2.0 version of https://github.com/valums/file-uploader to upload files and i am on Rails 2.3.5. Apache with passenger is my server.
Is there anyway to pass the file to ffmpeg while it is being uploaded to the rails app ?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with ur question?